# AutoHotKey alt stays pressed

Tags: autohotkey, onkeypress

I have this script

```
+#^a:: 
SetTitleMatchMode 2
IfWinExist InterCounter
{
    WinActivate
    Send x
    Send !{ESC}
}
return
```

after using it, alt stays pressed and I have to press alt on my keyboard to get to normal state (no key pressed). If I forget to do it and type something, a key shortcut is initiated. If I type <kbd>SPACE</kbd> for example, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> is pressed.

I tried various things. `{Alt up}` and other. They did not work. Where is the problem? Is there a fix for my script?

Comment: what version of AutoHotkey are you using?

Comment: 1.1.11.01. After your question I went and downloaded the current stable (1.1.16.05) and tested out. Still the same behaviour.

Comment: I tested your script, only replaced "InterCounter" to "Notepad" and Alt key does not stays pressed after hotkey execution. I tested on Windows 8 x64.

Comment: Try to replace "InterCounter" with "Notepad" and use your code with notepad. Maybe Alt is down because something is doing InterCounter and not the script you posted. Also run your script with admin privileges.

Comment: Well, InterCounter is actually just a name of a notepad file. I am currently doing it with notepad - so the problem is not there. Also, I have been trying to use this script with Microsoft OneNote with the same results, so it's not target program specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

(would do that in a comment if I could)

try to `Send , {ALT down}{ALT up}` which should do the trick. If not something else is interfering, like a 3d party program. Try close everything on your system except notepad and the AHK-script and see if that helps.

Comment: I wrote that I tried {ALT up} and other things. One of them was the alt down alt up succession. It does not work.

Comment: Did you tried to close everything in case something else interferes?

Comment: yup. There was na article on autohotkey forum, that windows 8.1 is unfriendly with keys that can manipulate windows environment being controlled by 3rd party apps like AHK and that they are implementing it for win. However this is an uncomfirmed information.

Comment: For AHK v2.0 you have to write `Send "{Alt down}{Alt up}"`